# while statement and if statemen

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I got the code below from a Java tutorial from Oracle, it works just fine.

I understand how the `for`-, `while` loop and `if` statement works, however, I'm struggling to understand the `while` and `if` statement below.

Why everything is as it is in the while and if statement below?

```
class ContinueWithLabelDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String searchMe = "Look for a substring in me";
        String substring = "sub";
        boolean foundIt = false;

        int max = searchMe.length() - 
                  substring.length();

    test:
        for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
            int n = substring.length();
            int j = i;
            int k = 0;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (searchMe.charAt(j++) != substring.charAt(k++)) {
                    continue test;
                }
            }
            foundIt = true;
                break test;
        }
        System.out.println(foundIt ? "Found it" : "Didn't find it");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (n-- != 0) {
            if (searchMe.charAt(j++) != substring.charAt(k++)) {
                continue test;
            }
        }
```

**Explanation**

> While Statement

1.) While `n--`(first use `n` and `then decreement`) `!= 0`, keep running loop until `n reaches 0`.

2.) Until `n is not equal to 0`, it keeps entering `inside while loop`

3.) Once it enters inside `while loop` , it `validates if condition`.

> If Statement

```
if (searchMe.charAt(j++) != substring.charAt(k++))
```

`searchMe.charAt(j++)` // character at `j++` location of `searchMe String`

`substring.charAt(k++)` // character at `k++` location of `substring String`

`If statement` actually matches the character at given positions from both the strings

eg.

```
String searchMe = "Look for a substring in me";
String substring = "sub";
```

at any given instance, `j = 3, k= 1`

`searchMe.charAt(4)` // returns character `k`, remember index start from `0`

`substring.charAt(1)` // returns character `u`, remember index start from `0`

If compares something like this,

```
if('k' != 'u')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! greatly appreciated!!

Comment: @dzjustinli please accept if the answer fully satisfied you. Up-vote as well if possible. Another user having questions might find this one.

Comment: @dzjustinli answer edited to answer further q's, hope it is clear now

Comment: You should also explain the label part, maybe note how not-so-common they are as well.

Comment: @Emz label i did not get you..??

Comment: `test:` and `break test;`

Comment: @ankur-singhal thank you so so much!! cant believe how detailed your explanation is!! suddenly everything became so clear to me. Just want you to know I really appreciate your help. Have accepted and up-voted the answer already.

Comment: @Emz thanks for the concern. Fortunately the "break test" part is the one of few parts that I do understand. lol thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

Continuing the above explanation I would like to add that the code has a label as well,

```
test:
for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
    int n = substring.length();
    int j = i;
    int k = 0;
    while (n-- != 0) {
        if (searchMe.charAt(j++) != substring.charAt(k++)) {
            continue test;
        }
    }
    foundIt = true;
        break test;
}
```

test here is a java label,the statement

```
continue test
```

sends the control to the next iteration of the for loop in case the if block executes successfully,for example in the above case for

```
j=3 and k=1
searchMe.charAt(i) //gives k
substring.charAt(k) //gives u
```

After comparing like said above

```
if(k!=u)
continue test //control goes to the for loop from here and next iteration is executed
```

Also in case if block is not executed

```
break test // makes the control come out of the for loop
```